# How to hide hard disk size in volume name?

Tags: nautilus

How to hide hard disk size in volume name?I just want to show volume name alone.

[image]

Comment: I think this problem should be reported to the nautilus team, because it is very annoying when you use the keyboard to find the harddisk by name, that you want to open. It would be better to have that information in grey text *under* the harddisk-name. (e.g. `(200 of 250 GB used)`)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This "feature" has already been reported to the nautilus team (see [gnome-bugs #593405](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=593405)) and marked `NOTABUG`, however its [triaged](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/388904) on Ubuntu so you might see this fixed in Oneiric.

---

### How to fix it:

I made a patch that reverts the upstream commit that added this feature. You'll need a bit of console work to apply it:

1. `mkdir gvfs; cd gvfs`
2. `sudo apt-get build-dep gvfs`
3. `apt-get source gvfs`
4. `wget https://launchpadlibrarian.net/77889392/100_remove_redundant_labels2.patch`
5. `cd gvfs-*/; quilt import ../100_remove_redundant_labels2.patch`
6. `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -rfakeroot`
7. `sudo dpkg -i ../*.deb`
8. Restart your computer

---

[image: After I applied the patch]

Comment: re step 5: It may return an error if gvfs package is in different version. It did today in my case. If that happens you simply issue the `ls` command to list the dir contents and note the gvfs version. In my case it was `gvfs-1.10.0` so I had to modify the command from step 5 to be `cd gvfs-1.10.0/; quilt import ../100_remove_redundant_labels2.patch`

Answer (score 3):

You should report this to the nautilus team as this is how Nautilus was told to display disks (it seems), outside those disks that are the active file system (from what i've been able to see in practical testing).

Answer (score 0):

I would report this as a bug. Will look into possible fixes for the error in the meantime.