# Nautilus - Can I set nautilus not to display the drive size, just the name?

Tags: nautilus, drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to hide hard disk size in volume name?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35955/how-to-hide-hard-disk-size-in-volume-name)

Is there any way to disable or at least change the way Nautilus displays Drives? 
My drives show up as such 
Size of disk: Diskname 
ex: 1.0 TB Hard Disk: DataStore

I have the drive labeled DataStore, but when I open Nautilus under Computer it shows
1.0 TB Hard Disk: DataStore, It would be great if it simply said DataStore to make it easier to jump around with the keyboard.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I don't find an option like that in nautilus :/

Comment: Question/Issue is the same as this question. [How to hide hard disk size in volume name?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/35955/how-to-hide-hard-disk-size-in-volume-name) Please check before posting a duplicate question.